# how to cancel the time scheduled cron job in java?

Tags: java

```
  public class CronTriggerApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {

                SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

                JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Main.class)
                        .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();
     System.out.println(job);
                Date startTime = DateBuilder.nextGivenSecondDate(null, 5);
     System.out.println(startTime);
                // run every 20 seconds infinite loop
                CronTrigger crontrigger = TriggerBuilder
                        .newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("TwentySec", "group1")
                        .startAt(startTime)
                        .startNow()
                        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("* * * ? * *"))//0 53 12 * * ? *
                        .build();

                scheduler.start();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, crontrigger);

                 //scheduler.shutdown();

            } catch (SchedulerException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

public class Main implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
    {

        System.out.println("Trigger Starts.."+new Date());
        System.out.println("ALL_OFF");

    }
}
```

**By using above code i can able to schedule cron job..but if want cancel the schedule time how can able to cancel or stop the schedule task?**
*can any one plz help me how can i stop or cancel the scheduled task?*

Answer (score 0):

You can expose an endpoint to interrupt it. And use the following function of scheduler to stop it.
            
    scheduler.interrupt(jobDetail.getKey());

Comment: Thank you Piyush.But where i wnat to write that function scheduler.interrupt(jobDetail.getKey());

Comment: In which class i want to write that your given function?

Comment: That you need to decide. If you are running job on server (that is listening on some port ) than you can expose an endpoint to interrupt it. (Rest api which will call that function.).  
If it is just a simple java program, you need to decide when you want to interrupt. it (on error, exception, etc....).